# Dismiss keyboard from view model in MVVMCross in Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a textview and a button on screen. User taps on the text view which shows up keyboard, user types some text and then clicks on the button whose  onclick is bound to a command defined in the view model.

I want to dismiss keyboard from view model by sending a message or calling a method in the view but still want to keep loose coupling between view and view model. I see mvvmmessenger, mvxinteraction etc to accomplish this. What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if this is the best way to handle this, but hopefully the way i did it can help you out.

I made an interface called IPlatformAction in the Core project, which implements a method called DismissKeyboard.

```
 public interface IPlatformAction
 {
     void DismissKeyboard();
 }
```

Then I made a service called PlatformActionService in the Droid project, that implements that interface.

```
public class PlatformService : IPlatformAction
{
    protected Activity CurrentActivity =>
        Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity>().Activity;

    public void DismissKeyboard()
    {
        var currentFocus = CurrentActivity.CurrentFocus;
        if (currentFocus != null)
        {
            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)CurrentActivity.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
            inputMethodManager.HideSoftInputFromWindow(currentFocus.WindowToken, HideSoftInputFlags.None);
        }
    }

}
```

Lastly, I inject the interface in the viewmodel and call the dismiss keyboard method

```
public class SomeViewModel : BaseViewModel<SomeModel>
{

    private readonly IPlatformAction _platformAction;

    public SomeViewModel(IPlatformAction platformAction)
    {
        _platformAction = platformAction;
    }

    public async Task DoSomething() 
    {
        //Some code 
        _platformAction.DismissKeyboard();
    }

}
```

Comment: get error on Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity>().Activity;

Comment: Does the error have a message or is it any hints in the stacktrace of what went wrong @Mehdico ?